# How to correctly set up a WebSocketProvider in ethers.js?

Tags: blockchain, ethers.js, web3-providers

I'm trying to switch my dapp from Web3Provider to WebSocketProvider,

form this:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_accounts" })
const account = accounts[0]
const signer = provider.getSigner()
```

to this:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider("ws://localhost:8545") <-
const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_accounts" })
const account = accounts[0]
const signer = provider.getSigner()
```

With this change I can interact with the Contract only with account that creates and deploy the smart contract, also, the transactions have no confirmation from the user. However, when I try to call some Contract function with another address I get this error:

[image]

On the fourth line, the value of the "from" key is different from the address actually selected in the metamask, in fact it is the address of the creator of the Smart Contract. There seems to be some problem with the signer or what? With Web3Provider everything works fine.

Can you help me in any way or tell me more about WebSocketProvider?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of ethers.js you use?

Comment: I just checked the version with npm list ethers and seems to be the @5.7.2 version. 
Only this dependency has a different version:
hardhat-gas-reporter@1.0.9
 eth-gas-reporter@0.2.25
  ethers@4.0.49

Comment: Then i assume the problem is somewhere in your localhost websockets (ws). I would suggest registering on alchemy and creating new app, then use their wss link to check if it will work as expected with it. you need the "wss://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/api-key-here". You need to do this on any official testnet though.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried it and I got "Error: unknown account #0...". I think I figured out what the error is, but I don't know how to solve it. It's something about the provider.getSigner() method that fails to get the address selected in metamask, which is understandable because I don't pass window.ethereum in provider creation, but I also try to do it passing confingOptions as a third argument in WebSocketProvider(), but nothing changes. Really don't how to handle this